# Trying to create QuoteDocument via API failes

Tags: api, quote

I'm working on a PE with API enabled and I'm trying to create a QuoteDocument.
For some reason this failed with error:

> sObject type 'QuoteDocument' is not supported. If you are attempting
>   to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.

This is the JS on my VF page that is trying to do the creation:

```
<script>
        function uploadQuoteDocument( filecontent,  quoteId) {
            var quoteDocument  = new sforce.SObject('QuoteDocument');
            quoteDocument.Document = filecontent;
            quoteDocument.QuoteId = quoteId;
            var result = sforce.connection.create([quoteDocument]);
            if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
                alert('Quote PDF successfully generated');
                window.location.href = '/{!Quote.Id}';
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                alert('Quote PDF generation failed');
            }
        }
<script>
```

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? It's likely though you need to refer to it as QuoteDocument__c

Comment: Code added. It is working fine in my Dev org so I don't think its a __c issue

Comment: Can you see the any of the Quote, QuoteDocument, QuoteLineItem sObjects if you connect with the same user with a tool like [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or the [Force.com Explorer](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ForceExplorer)?

Comment: Yes, I can query them and see them

Comment: I know in PE page layout acts as field level security (if page lay says the field is readonly you'll have hard time writing to that field if you're not a SysAdmin). So maybe there's a Tab visibility that's missing or something like that? Can you access existing Quotes/QuoteDocs without problems?

Comment: @eyescream In the quote page layout I can see the Quote PDFs related list. I can click the view and send as email links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting... I have some ideas, too much to put in a comment.

Add `sforce.debug.trace=true;` to the beginning of your method.

Regarding the API version don't be so sure you're using v. 26, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/23556030/313628.

Any special reason why it has to be done in javascript and not pure VF + apex?

```
insert new QuoteDocument(
    Document = Blob.toPDf('Test PDF content'),
    QuoteId = '0Q070000000OjV9'
);
```

Some `<apex:input>` field with  should work too and be much cleaner... And if you don't want an inputField but JS way is giving you hard time you could still try with marking an apex method as [webservice](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_and_ajax.htm) (oldschool way) or [remoteaction](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm). Server-side code should bypass any weird "*no-Profiles-but-still*" security settings in PE (I've recently had a security review and had to slap CRUD checks all over the place. Turns out managed code was bypassing the PE's "security by page layout" just fine like in orgs that really have Profiles).

Last but not least: what are you getting when you execute this (or matching [describe operation in Ajax toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm))?

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Schema.SobjectType.QuoteDocument;
System.debug(dsr.isAccessible() + ', ' + dsr.isCreateable());
```

Comment: many thanks, it was the API level issue. I used         <apex:includeScript value="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" /> which doesn't work. Now I'm using     <script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> it works perfectly...

Comment: Weird bug in includeScript then? Interesting! What if you'd use path that starts from root instead of going "up" twice? Many thanks for accepting but it feels bit wrong, it was just a couple of hints :) Still - depending how much time you have on your hands you might decide to do it with more server-side in mind, especially that they continue to improve it: https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring14/Visualforce+Remote+Objects. The connection.js just brings back the not too find memories from my S-Control days...

Comment: I don't have access to APEX in PE this is why I had to workaround it with JS on the page side

Comment: I was under impression that you're developing a managed package, that's why I've suggested these, sorry :) PEs can use apex-based solutions from managed packages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure quotes are enabled.
2. Make sure you are using a modern version of the API (at least 18).
3. Make sure the user has profile permissions, if you're using custom profiles.

Comment: Quotes are enabled; I'm using API 26.0. There are no profiles in this org since its a Professional Edition with API enabled

Comment: That's odd, then. I'll check around and see if I can find anything else.